# Site on mobile appears to be zoomed in even though I have a meta viewport. Is there something I'm missing?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

When I was editing the media queries everything seemed fine. Then I uploaded and noticed the zoomed-in effect when the site first loads. I have a meta viewport tag and media queries in place but I can't figure out what's wrong.

I've tried changing the CSS multiple times and different viewport scales but I can't get it to zoom out like I want it to. I'm just trying to have it look normal on mobile without having to zoom out when you open the site.

The website is:
https://trexperts.myfsoservice.com/pipelinequestionaire.html

The viewport I'm using is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with the `<meta>` tag. There are a few things going on here that are causing this. Most of it is some hardcoded widths and some things that aren't really responsive.

First, I'd add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your global styles with this:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will add `box-sizing: border-box;` to all elements, which will make it more consistent when it comes to handling widths. Now, the padding will be included in the width, instead of added.

Second, `#bottom` has a hard set width of `width: 650px;`. This is making the page scroll. Here, we should set the width to `width: 100%;` and set the max-width to `max-width: 650px;`.

Third, taking a look at the header image, it's got a `margin-left: 50%;`. Remove that. It's pushing the logo off the screen. You might want more resizing of this item.

Finally, remove the `margin-left: 35%` on `#form_container`. It would be better to use something like `margin: 0 auto;`. This way it would center `#form_container` without requiring you to use a percentage left margin.

In the end, this should make the `#form_container` take up the full space without extra zoom – side scroll.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That seemed to help a bit but it seems its still taking up too much space and I have to side scroll a little. I keep looking over the CSS but I can't see whats making it too wide.

Comment: @BroD Do you have a design of the end goal? There is more I can change. I just didn’t know the end design.

Comment: I've made all the design changes and was happy with how everything looked until I tested the site on mobile and noticed problem. The end goal is just to have it look good on mobile with no zoom in or side scroll, just everything on the page.

Comment: I can do another pass at taking a design eye to it, if you would like. Should I give it a go?

Comment: If you don't mind. I ran the code through JSFiddle and it looks pretty good on mobile but I can't duplicate how it looks when I run it on chrome using the inspector tools. It might have something to do with the images not being present but this is how I was hoping it would look minus the empty images 
https://jsfiddle.net/DWeb151/64tys3Lf/3/show

Comment: @BroD here is a pass in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/heyyou/vnpgt2wa/11/

I added your images in by using the full URL — you'll want to make it relative again. I made several changes throughout the mobile CSS styles.

Comment: Thank you so much I think this fixed all my problems. Hopefully this wont happen again. When I was making the edits for the mobile side I had no idea the zoom in effect was even happening. It looking fine when I was editing it on chrome using the inspector tools using the device mobile toolbar.

Comment: @BroD could you upvote or mark this question as correct?